# Vue router created by API result and reuse of components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm fetching an array from an API and adding components to it based on the type. From this I will create the routes for Vue later. Example of the array after I have added components and children to it:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  uri: '/',
  title: 'title',
  component: require('../components/views/type1.vue).default,
  children: []
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  uri: '/page',
  title: 'title2',
  component: require('../components/views/type2.vue).default,
  children: [{id: 3, uri: 'subpage', title: 'title3', component: require('../components/views/type1.vue).default}]
 },
 {
  id: 4,
  uri: '/other-page',
  title: 'title4',
  component: require('../components/views/type2.vue).default,
  children: [{id: 5, uri: 'other-sub-page', title: 'title5', component: require('../components/views/type1.vue).default}]
 },
]
```

From this I'm creating Vue routes in a for loop:

```
//for-loop
routes.push({
    path: entries[i].uri,
    name:entries[i].title,
    component: entries[i].component,
    children: entries[i].children,
    meta:{
        entryId:entries[i].id
    }
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode:'history',
    routes
});
```

With this in place and the Vue instance created all the different routes with its child routes are working, but I have some problems:

- Randomly a child route is loading the wrong .vue file (even though the component path is correct in the array as this is debugged)
- This only happens with child routes.
- When loading the wrong component - it also print the same content as another component of the same type. Like they are identical. For example the route with id 3 (a child) prints the exact same result as id 1 even though the content should be different even though they are of the same type.

I'm guessing it has something to do with how I build the Vue routes, but I cant understand why it wont work. The array of "routes" looks perfectly fine when debugging it before passing it to Vue router.

**EDIT / TEMP SOLUTION**

> Problem is solved by using the full uri and just creating a flat
>   router array without children. Its something with the children that
>   causes this. So its working now with just a flat array of routes, but
>   I dont know if this will cause any problems/best practice etc.

Comment: When transitioning between two routes that use the same component, Vue will reuse the existing component instance. Could this be one of the issues you have?

Comment: It might be, but if I console.log from for example created() or mounted() in the component it does get called on all the different routes. But I did notice console.log($route.name) shows "undefined" in the component that bugs